# Cannot Copy a Text File through fwrite and fread in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, fwrite, fread

Here is the Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f, *fp;
    char buff[512];
    int buff_size;
    int bytes;

    fp = fopen("File.txt", "rb");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot Open Source File!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen("append.txt", "ab+");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot Open Target File!\n");
        fclose(fp);
        exit(1);
    }

    buff_size = sizeof(buff);

    while (bytes = fread(&buff, buff_size, 1, fp) > 0) {
        if (bytes > 0)
            fwrite(&buff, buff_size, 1, f);
        else
            break;

        printf("Appending...\n\n");
    }

    rewind(f);

    while (bytes = fread(&buff, buff_size, 1, f) > 0)
        if (bytes > 0)
            printf("%s", buff);


    fclose(fp);
    fclose(f);
}
```

So, it happens to be that this doesn't output anything and when I check the file "append.txt" it also does not contain anything.
Note that the Source File "File.txt" is not empty.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

**EDIT:**

I fixed the problem by replacing `buff_size` with `strlen(buff)` as this: 
`bytes = fread(&buff, strlen(buff), 1, f) > 0` and the same in `fwrite()` and second `fread()`.

Can someone explain why this worked?

Comment: Does your compiler give you any warnings about passing `&buff` to `fread()` and `fwrite()`?

Comment: @FelixPalmen No, it doesn't

Comment: well, it's not the reason for the problem, I just checked `fread()` takes `void *`. Still, you should leave out the `&`. `buff` will decay to `char *` (what you want), but `&buf` is `char (*)[512]`.

Comment: The line `while( bytes = fread(&buff, buff_size, 1, fp) > 0 )` doesn't do what you want it to do — you're missing the parentheses in `while((bytes = fread(&buff, buff_size, 1, fp)) > 0)`.  You also need to reverse the count and size arguments — you get a short read at the end of a file that is not an exact multiple of 512 bytes long, but you won't know about those bytes.

Comment: @FelixPalmen That didn't work too.

Comment: I said it's not the reason for the problem ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen Oh Ok

Comment: Also, you want to `fwrite` `bytes` bytes, not `buff_size` bytes. Likewise, the buffer is unlikely to end with `\0`, therefore your read loop should use `fwrite(buff 1, bytes, stdout);` instead of `printf`; and naturally that requires the reversal of the `fwrite` arguments.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Still, not fixed

Comment: also the `if (bytes > 0)` are kind of useless, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Nope, That too didn't work. Actually, the problem is in this line 
    bytes = fread(&buff, buff_size, 1, f) > 0    because it doesn't enter the loop.

Comment: @Ashar7 I didn't say this alone would fix it, just that there are about a dozen things wrong with your code!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I think so.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Wait, I found a fix. I'll edit the post

Comment: Your "fix" is **horribly** wrong.

Comment: "*Can someone explain me why this worked?*" -- because *undefined behavior* is undefined. C isn't a language for coding by *trial and error*.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yea it's not that kind of language and I'm very new to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
char buff[512];
int buff_size;

// [...]

bytes = fread(&buff, buff_size, 1, fp)
```

This will attempt to read one block of 512 bytes. The return value is the number of blocks read, so it won't be bytes. But leaving this aside, if your file is shorter than 512 bytes, this won't read *anything*.

What you want is read 512 times 1 byte, then you will get the byte count back, so swap places for `buff_size` and `1`.

---

Side notes:

- if you do your checks in the loop condition correctly like:

  ```
  while ((bytes = fread(buff, 1, buff_size, fp)) > 0 )
  ```

  the extra check for `if (bytes > 0)` is redundant.
- when writing, you only want to write the amount of bytes you actually read:

  ```
  fwrite(buff, 1, bytes, f);
  ```
- For sizes, always use `size_t` -- `int` could very well be wrong:

  ```
  size_t buff_size;
  size_t bytes;
  ```
- printing your `buff` with `printf("%s", )` is *undefined behavior* because you don't add a `'\0'` byte after the data read by `fread()`. A C string must end with `'\0'`. When the data read by `fread()` doesn't contain a `'\0'` by accident, `printf()` will read and use uninitialized data and possibly even read beyond the bounds of your `buff`.

Comment: Also mention that the verification phase has undefined behavior as `buff` is not necessarily a properly null terminated string.

Comment: @chqrlie added, thanks.

Comment: Technically, `int` is OK here as the return value of `fread` is in the range `0` to `sizeof buff`, which is small enough to fit in an `int`, but it is indeed better to use the proper types.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, I wrote *could* for a reason. Just pointing it out because it's a bad habit and I doubt OP would have used the correct type in a case he can't know the possible range :)

Answer (score 1):

Felix Palmen listed a number of problems in your code, your fix is completely wrong as `buff` does not even have a null terminator.

Here is a better version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f, *fp;
    char buff[512];
    size_t bytes;

    fp = fopen("File.txt", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open source file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen("append.txt", "ab+");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open target file!\n");
        fclose(fp);
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((bytes = fread(buff, 1, sizeof buff, fp)) != 0) {
        if (fwrite(buff, 1, bytes, 1, f) != bytes) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to the target file\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("Appending...\n\n");
    }

    rewind(f);

    while ((bytes = fread(buff, 1, sizeof buff, f)) != 0) {
        printf("%.*s", (int)bytes, buff);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bytes = fread(&buff, buff_size, 1, fp) > 0
```

Take a look at the [C Precedence Chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The operator `>` is above `=`, so the return value of `fread` will be compared to zero, and then the result of that comparison will be stored in `bytes`. You intended to write this

```
(bytes = fread(&buff, buff_size, 1, fp)) > 0
```

Comment: Actually your fix is only partial: for `bytes` to receive the number of bytes read, the arguments must be passed in the opposite order: `(bytes = fread(buff, `, buff_size, fp)) > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to your problem, given fixed file names.  Were it my own code, it would take the file names as arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char src_file[] = "File.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(src_file, "rb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot Open Source File '%s'!\n", src_file);
        return(1);
    }

    const char tgt_file[] = "append.txt";
    FILE *f = fopen(tgt_file, "ab+");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot Open Target File '%s'!\n", tgt_file);
        fclose(fp);
        return(1);
    }

    char buff[512];
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = fread(buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(buff), fp)) > 0)
    {
        fwrite(buff, sizeof(char), bytes, f);
        printf("Appending...\n\n");
    }

    rewind(f);

    while ((bytes = fread(buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(buff), f)) > 0)
        printf("%.*s", bytes, buff);

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

There are a variety of fixes, most of them articulated in comments somewhere along the line.

- I made the file names into arrays so that the name could be used in both `fopen()` and in the error messages, which are printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  This is helpful to other users in generalized code.  If the file names come from command line arguments, it is trivial.
- The calls to `fread()` were fixed so that the number of bytes is reported, rather than the number of 512-byte blocks (which will be 0 or 1).  This involved reversing the order of the size/count arguments to `fread()`.  The buffer was passed rather than the address of the buffer, too.
- The number of bytes read was captured correctly.
- The number of bytes read was used to control the size of the `fwrite()`.
- The number of bytes read was used to control the number of bytes printed by `printf()`.
- I don't like the special rule in C99 and later that allows `main()` — but only `main()` — to return 0 by default.  AFAIAC, it's a function defined as returning an `int`; it should return an `int`.  However, there are others who disagree.

Comment: While technically correct, `fread(buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(buff), fp)` looks bogus: it should either read `fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), fp)` or `fread(buff, sizeof(*buff), countof(buff), fp)` or possibly `fread(buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(buff) / sizeof(char), fp)`. For any larger type, your form would fail.

Comment: @chqrlie: I disagree, but if I were using a different type, the result variable would not be `bytes` but `items` or some other aggregate name. If I was reading units of `struct SomeStruct` into an array `struct SomeStruct array[ARRAY_SIZE]`, I'd be using `int num_read = fread(array, sizeof(array[0]), ARRAY_SIZE, fp);` or similar. I'd not be interested in the number of bytes read; I'd be interested in the number of complete structures read. In this example, I'm interested in `char`, so I use `sizeof(char)` for the size; the number of `char` available in the array happens to be `sizeof(buffer)`.

Comment: You can't code in C by rote.  You always have to think.

Comment: I beg to disagree: regardless of the name of the target variable, using 2 instances of `sizeof` as arguments to `fread` only happens to work if one or the other evaluates to `1`. This is an eye-catcher that calls for head scratching, and sets a bad example for casual readers who will not immediately grasp that `sizeof(char) == 1` and may use the same syntax for other types.